# convert string to map in javascript

Tags: javascript

how to convert the following string to map so that i can access the values

```
data.message ="{"id":"60653","key":"project1","self":"http://127.0.0.1:321/rest/api/2/issue/project1"}"
```

Comment: change external double quotes to single quotes, or remove them, otherwise it's syntax error.

Comment: Thats the JSONresponse including double quotes

Comment: If the source is indeed a string though, instead of you writing down a string, then JSON.parse() is what you are after.

Comment: `var obj = JSON.parse(data.message);` will give you an object with properties you can access.

Comment: Is that your actual code or are you just trying to represent the data you're getting? It's extremely confusing because it's invalid syntax so it's unclear if you're having problems with that or what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 1):

if your string is a valid JSON just use the `JSON.parse` function:

```
var str = '{"id":"60653","key":"project1","self":"http://127.0.0.1:321/rest/api/2/issue/project1"}'
var mydata = JSON.parse(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.parse

Here's the corresponding MDN documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse